# Cant deserialize a list from DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, xml, datacontractserializer

Im on C# and Im having trouble deserializing a List from an XML file I created used DataContractSerializer wich has a List of entities from Entity Framework in it, the code I used is this:

```
List<Proveedores> proveedores = ObtenerEntidadesProveedores();

foreach (Proveedores proveedor in proveedores)
{
    proveedor.ProveedoresDomicilios.Load();
}

Type[] tipoColeccion = new Type[1];
tipoColeccion[0] = typeof(Proveedores);

DataContractSerializer serializador = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<Proveedores>), tipoColeccion);
serializador.WriteObject(entrada, proveedores);
salida = entrada;
```

Im using DataContractSerializer  because it will map all the related entities from Proveedores to the XML.

Now the problem is that when I try to get it back, I get a List with only one element:

```
List<Proveedores> proveedores = new List<Proveedores>();

Type[] tipoColeccion = new Type[1];
tipoColeccion[0] = typeof(Proveedores);

DataContractSerializer serializador = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<Proveedores>), tipoColeccion);
proveedores = serializador.ReadObject(entrada) as List<Proveedores>;
```

When the generated XML has lots of them like this:

```
<ArrayOfProveedores xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MxPOS10.Sistema.Datos" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Proveedores z:Id="i1" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
        <EntityKey z:Id="i2" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Objects.DataClasses" xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data">
            <a:EntityContainerName>MxPOSv10r1Entidades</a:EntityContainerName>
                <a:EntityKeyValues>
                    <a:EntityKeyMember>
                        <a:Key>IDProveedor</a:Key>
                        <a:Value i:type="b:int" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">0</a:Value>
                    </a:EntityKeyMember>
                </a:EntityKeyValues>
            <a:EntitySetName>Proveedores</a:EntitySetName>
        </EntityKey>
        <Compras/>
        <Dumb i:nil="true"/>
        <IDProveedor>0</IDProveedor>
        <Nombre>PANADERIAS DEL CENTRO</Nombre>
        <ProveedoresContacto/>
        <ProveedoresDomicilios/>
        <RFC>98982u24ujjjj</RFC>
        <RegistroActivo>false</RegistroActivo>
    </Proveedores>

    <.... more Proveedores ....>

</ArrayOfProveedores>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: This must be somehow related to the definition of `Proveedores`, or something else you're not telling us, because it works fine with a simple `Proveedores` class.

Comment: Hi, the definition of Proveedores has never been touched since it was provided by the Entity Framework and it can be serializated with no problems, because I get the XML with a list of all the Proveedores objects I have on my DB...

Answer (score 0):

Whatever object you are serializing to, set up like this. What this does is, sets a collectiondata contract with your element, Proveedore(s)

```
    [DataContract(Name = "Proveedore", Namespace = "")]
    public class Proveedores {

    }

    [CollectionDataContract(Name = "ArrayOfProveedores", ItemName = "Proveedore", Namespace = "")]
    public class ProveedoresList : List<Proveedores> {

    }
    public class FileRead{
        [DataMember(Name = "ArrayOfProveedores", Order = 0)]
        public ProveedoresList Pros { get; private set; }
    }
```